# How can I handle MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException when TokenAcquisition fails?

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, .net-5

I'm building a webapp and keep encountering the following error when I restart the app and try to request a token using `ITokenAcquisition.GetTokenForUserAsync`

> "One or more errors occurred. (IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. )"

I'm authenticating Users against Azure AD using Microsoft.Identity.Web.

When I inspect the token cache, it is empty after restarting the app. If the user was already signed in from an earlier session or because they are using a Domain joined device they seem to bypass the cache.

How do I force reauthentication or add a token to the cache?

Startup.cs

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
           {
               // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
               options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
               options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
               // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
               options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
           });
           // Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
           services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
               .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "https://database.windows.net//.default" })
               .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

           services.AddAuthorization(options =>
           {
               // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
               options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
           });

           services.AddDbContext<MyDatabaseContext>(options =>
                   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyAzureConnection")));

           services.AddRazorPages()
               .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
               .AddMvcOptions(o => o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()))
               .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

       }
```

My DbContext where I request the token

```
        public MyDatabaseContext (ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
                            DbContextOptions<MyDatabaseContext> options)
                            : base(options)
        {
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
            var token = _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] {"https://database.windows.net//.default"});
            var connection = (SqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();
            connection.AccessToken = token.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

All my PageModels are decorated with `[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "AzureSQL:BaseUrl")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-error-handling-dotnet#common-net-exceptions) means:

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
> application with ID '{appId}' named '{appName}'. Send an interactive
> authorization request for this user and resource.

[image]

#### Mitigation:

Get user consent first. If you aren't using .NET Core (which doesn't have any Web UI), call (once only) `AcquireTokeninteractive`. If you are using .NET core or don't want to do an `AcquireTokenInteractive`, the user can navigate to a URL to give consent: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&scope=user.read`. to call `AcquireTokenInteractive`: `app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAccount(account).WithClaims(ex.Claims).ExecuteAsync();`

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction. I borrowed heavily from a service in Microsoft.Identity.Web which contained a ChallengeUser method (following link).
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/a2844fe47a5844c3cdadb2644678abe7f04f4bde/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/MicrosoftIdentityCircuitHandler.cs#L193

Answer (score 3):

In my case I encountered `MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException` while working on a .Net Core 3.1 Web App. My code in controller action:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation" };
try
{
    ViewData["token"] = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
    return View();
}
catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
{
    throw ex.MsalUiRequiredException;
}
```

Notice the catch block. `MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException` has a property to access `MsalUiRequiredException`. I had to throw that exception to force Identity Web UI to show the consent UI again. I got that tip from [this link](https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent). Look at MVC Controllers section in it. It says,

> AuthorizeForScopesAttribute inherits from ExceptionFilterAttribute which means that it processes the MSAL.NET MsalUiRequiredException to handle conditional access and incremental consent. This also means that if you catch MSAL exception, you should re-throw the caught MSAL exceptions so that the attribute can handle it

The second sentence made my day! It should have been highlighted to save us time.

P.S. This was my sample app while preparing for AZ204. I had not included storage impersonation scope in the beginning but added it later. Then app started throwing above mentioned exception and I had to find a way to show the Consent UI again.